# How to edit rows in detailslist fluent react UI

Tags: css, reactjs, fluent

I am working with Fluent react UI. I want to edit rows in the table. Is there any option?
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/detailslist

Answer (score 0):

I recommend FluentUI Editable DetailsList. The following example/library has excellent customization to edit on grid/table. It also have other features like column-based filter, bulk edit, bulk delete, and so on.

GitHub Repo: https://github.com/microsoft/FluentUIEditableDetailsList

Working Example: https://editabledetailslist.azurewebsites.net/

The examples are right forward and easy to use. I am currently using it in my SPFx Webpart project with react. You can install using the npm and use the example on the repository to play around.

**Install Package on your project**

```
npm i fluentui-editable-grid
```

**Usage**

```
import { DetailsListLayoutMode, mergeStyles, mergeStyleSets, SelectionMode, TextField } from '@fluentui/react';
import { EditableGrid, EditControlType, IColumnConfig, EventEmitter, EventType, NumberAndDateOperators } from 'fluentui-editable-grid';
import { Fabric } from 'office-ui-fabric-react';
import * as React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';

const Consumer = () => {
    const classNames = mergeStyleSets({
        controlWrapper: {
        display: 'flex',
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
        }
    });
  
const [items, setItems] = useState<any[]>([]);
const columns: IColumnConfig[] = [
    {
        key: 'id',
        name: 'ID',
        text: 'ID',
        editable: false,
        dataType: 'number',
        minWidth: 100,
        maxWidth: 100,
        isResizable: true,
        includeColumnInExport: true,
        includeColumnInSearch: true,
        applyColumnFilter: true,
        disableSort: true
    },
    {
        key: 'customerhovercol',
        name: 'Custom Hover Column',
        text: 'Custom Hover Column',
        editable: true,
        dataType: 'string',
        minWidth: 100,
        maxWidth: 100,
        isResizable: true,
        includeColumnInExport: false,
        includeColumnInSearch: false,
        applyColumnFilter: false,
        disableSort: true,
        hoverComponentOptions: { enable:true, hoverChildComponent: <CellHover customProps={{ someProp: '' }} /> }
    },
    {
        key: 'name',
        name: 'Name',
        text: 'Name',
        editable: true,
        dataType: 'string',
        minWidth: 100,
        maxWidth: 100,
        isResizable: true,
        includeColumnInExport: true,
        includeColumnInSearch: true,
        applyColumnFilter: true
    },
    {
        key: 'age',
        name: 'Age',
        text: 'Age',
        editable: true,
        dataType: 'number',
        minWidth: 100,
        maxWidth: 100,
        isResizable: true,
        includeColumnInExport: true,
        includeColumnInSearch: true,
        applyColumnFilter: true
    },
    {
        key: 'designation',
        name: 'Designation',
        text: 'Designation',
        editable: true,
        dataType: 'string',
        minWidth: 100,
        maxWidth: 100,
        isResizable: true,
        includeColumnInExport: true,
        includeColumnInSearch: true,
        inputType: EditControlType.MultilineTextField,
        applyColumnFilter: true
    },
    {
        key: 'salary',
        name: 'Salary',
        text: 'Salary',
        editable: true,
        dataType: 'number',
        minWidth: 100,
        maxWidth: 100,
        isResizable: true,
        includeColumnInExport: false,
        includeColumnInSearch: true,
        maxLength:5,
        applyColumnFilter: true,
        cellStyleRule: { 
            enable: true, 
            rule: { 
                operator : NumberAndDateOperators.LESSTHAN, 
                value: 50000 
            }, 
            whenTrue: { textColor: '#EF5350', fontWeight: 'bold' },
            whenFalse: { textColor: '#9CCC65' }
        }
    },
    {
        key: 'dateofjoining',
        name: 'Date of Joining',
        text: 'Date of Joining',
        editable: true,
        dataType: 'date',
        minWidth: 150,
        maxWidth: 150,
        isResizable: true,
        includeColumnInExport: true,
        includeColumnInSearch: true,
        inputType: EditControlType.Date
    },
    {
        key: 'payrolltype',
        name: 'Payroll Type',
        text: 'Payroll Type',
        editable: true,
        dataType: 'string',
        minWidth: 150,
        maxWidth: 150,
        isResizable: true,
        includeColumnInExport: true,
        includeColumnInSearch: true,
        inputType: EditControlType.DropDown,
        dropdownValues: [
            { key: 'weekly', text: 'Weekly' },
            { key: 'biweekly', text: 'Bi-Weekly' },
            { key: 'monthly', text: 'Monthly' }
        ]
    },
    {
        key: 'employmenttype',
        name: 'Employment Type',
        text: 'Employment Type',
        editable: true,
        dataType: 'string',
        minWidth: 200,
        maxWidth: 200,
        isResizable: true,
        includeColumnInExport: true,
        includeColumnInSearch: true,
        inputType: EditControlType.Picker,
        pickerOptions: {
            pickerTags: ['Employment Type1', 'Employment Type2', 'Employment Type3', 'Employment Type4', 'Employment Type5', 'Employment Type6', 'Employment Type7', 'Employment Type8', 'Employment Type9', 'Employment Type10', 'Employment Type11', 'Employment Type12'],
            minCharLimitForSuggestions: 2,
            tagsLimit: 1,
            pickerDescriptionOptions: { 
                enabled: true, 
                values: [
                    { key: 'Employment Type1', description: 'Employment Type1 Description'},
                    { key: 'Employment Type2', description: 'Employment Type2 Description'},
                    { key: 'Employment Type3', description: 'Employment Type3 Description'},
                    { key: 'Employment Type4', description: 'Employment Type4 Description'},
                    { key: 'Employment Type5', description: 'Employment Type5 Description'},
                    { key: 'Employment Type6', description: 'Employment Type6 Description'},
                    { key: 'Employment Type7', description: 'Employment Type7 Description'},
                    { key: 'Employment Type8', description: 'Employment Type8 Description'},
                    { key: 'Employment Type9', description: 'Employment Type9 Description'},
                    { key: 'Employment Type10', description: 'Employment Type10 Description'},
                    { key: 'Employment Type11', description: 'Employment Type11 Description'},
                    { key: 'Employment Type12', description: 'Employment Type12 Description'},
            ] },
            suggestionsRule: StringOperators.STARTSWITH
        }
    }
];

const SetDummyData = () : void => {
    const dummyData = [
        {
            id: "1",
            customerhovercol: 'Hover Me',
            name: "Name1",
            age:32,
            designation:'Designation1',
            salary:57000,
            dateofjoining:'2010-04-01T14:57:10',
            payrolltype: 'Weekly',
            employmenttype: 'Employment Type11'
        },
        {
            id: "2",
            customerhovercol: 'Hover Me',
            name: "Name2",
            age:27,
            designation:'Designation2',
            salary:42000,
            dateofjoining:'2014-06-09T14:57:10',
            payrolltype: 'Monthly',
            employmenttype: 'Employment Type4'
        },
        {
            id: "3",
            customerhovercol: 'Hover Me',
            name: "Name3",
            age:35,
            designation:'Designation3',
            salary:75000,
            dateofjoining:'2005-07-02T14:57:10',
            payrolltype: 'Weekly',
            employmenttype: 'Employment Type7'
        },
        {
            id: "4",
            customerhovercol: 'Hover Me',
            name: "Name4",
            age:30,
            designation:'Designation4',
            salary:49000,
            dateofjoining:'2019-04-01T14:57:10',
            payrolltype: 'Bi-Weekly',
            employmenttype: 'Employment Type2'
        }
    ];
    setItems(dummyData);
}

React.useEffect(() => {
    SetDummyData();
}, []);

return (
    <Fabric>
        <div className={classNames.controlWrapper}>
            <TextField placeholder='Search Grid' className={mergeStyles({ width: '60vh', paddingBottom:'10px' })} onChange={(event) => EventEmitter.dispatch(EventType.onSearch, event)}/>
        </div>
        <EditableGrid
            id={1}
            columns={columns}
            items={items}
            enableCellEdit={true}
            enableExport={true}
            enableTextFieldEditMode={true}
            enableTextFieldEditModeCancel={true}
            enableGridRowsDelete={true}
            enableGridRowsAdd={true}
            height={'70vh'}
            width={'140vh'}
            position={'relative'}
            enableUnsavedEditIndicator={true}
            //onGridSave={onGridSave}
            enableGridReset={true}
            enableColumnFilters={true}
            enableColumnFilterRules={true}
            enableRowAddWithValues={{enable : true, enableRowsCounterInPanel : true}}
            layoutMode={DetailsListLayoutMode.justified}
            selectionMode={SelectionMode.multiple}
            enableRowEdit={true}
            enableRowEditCancel={true}
            enableBulkEdit={true}
            enableColumnEdit={true}
            enableSave={true}
        />
    </Fabric>
);
};

export default Consumer;
}
```